# MySql too many connection when i use hibernate template?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

After 100 hits to mysql we are getting  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections".

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TechDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"></property>
        <property name="username" value="xxxxx"></property>
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx"></property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="30" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />

    </bean>

<bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>jobseeker.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">19</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: After 100 hits to database we are getting "too many connections" message and application hangs.

Comment: When you get this exception? After which operation? You must search solution in your source and your question is not clear.

Comment: The sessions should be closed after the end of the usage. If you're using local transactions, then you should manage them yourself: add a `Session#close()` at the end.

Comment: Which version of hibernate you are using ? we faced same issue with hibernate as c3p0 pool connections were not closed properly.After updating hibernate it worked fine.

Comment: I am using hibernate3.jar,hibernate-core3.6.3.jar

Comment: I am using hibernate 3

Comment: Here I am using Spring-Hibernate Template so no need to open and close connections . Spring-Hibernate Template should look after automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your java code once you serve the request make sure that the connection is closed.

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    // the actual code goes here
} finally {
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

Comment: we are  using Spring-hibernate template then no need to open and close the connections. Connection management should happen by hibernate template automatically. That why we choose hibernate template..

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the default max_connections value is 151. If you want more connections.

you can set that in /etc/my.cnf

```
You can increase this value in main config file (e.g., /etc/my.cnf) using this syntax:
[mysqld]
set-variable
max_connections=5000
```

see the following link for more information Mysql Doc (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/too-many-connections.html)